# Program is not working on leetcode, 14. Longest common prefix

Tags: c

Is it true that leetcode site sometimes doesn't work? I have been struggling for 2 weeks, but failed to find where is the problem.

```
char *longestCommonPrefix(char **strs, int strsSize) {
    static char retStr[100] = { '\0' };
    unsigned int matchTillPos;
    
    for (int i = (strsSize == 1 ? 0 : 1); i < strsSize; i++) {
        matchTillPos = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(strs[i]); j++) {
            if (strs[0][j] == strs[i][j]) {
                matchTillPos++;
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    if (matchTillPos != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matchTillPos; i++)
            retStr[i] = strs[0][i];
        return retStr;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Why don't you sort them? I think this would be much faster since you only need to check the ends, then, (like a trie.)

Comment: It's safe to assume that the problem is in your code, not in the compilers or the test sites.

Comment: You should include sufficient of the problem description in the question that it's possible to see how your code relates to the inputs and outputs.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.

Comment: As @JonathanLeffler stated - the problem is always in your code.

Comment: leetcode should show you which test has failed, so you can debug locally with test inputs

Comment: @0___________  please see this is the test case where my code is failing ["ab", "a"] according to leetcode it should return  only a and actually it is returning "a" i have checked on leetcode too it is showing output is "a" but after submitting it shows that my code is returning "al" i don't know from where this "l" came.

Please see image: https://i.postimg.cc/X7BzVFRS/Inkedleetcode-loqngest.jpg

Comment: Do you null-terminate your string?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler please see my above comment for image

Comment: @JonathanLeffler are you talking about this string `static char retStr[100] = {'\0'};` ? i don't terminate as it is a string with 100 null terminated chars

Comment: The problem constraints say the strings can be up to 200 characters long, so it isn't clear that 100 is long enough.  When I see a comment about “I expected a and got ai”, I immediately wonder about null termination. Remember that the function might be called many times, but the static return buffer is only initialized once, logically at program startup.  If you don't explicitly null-terminate the string, you get whatever is left over from previous uses of the function.  It is best to explicitly terminate your strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the maximum string length is specified as 200, so the `static` array for the result should have a length of at least 201 bytes.
- you compute `matchTillPos` for each string and only remember the last value. You should instead keep track of the smallest value.
- if there is a single string, you should return the full string.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <string.h>

char *longestCommonPrefix(char **strs, int strsSize) {
    static char retStr[201];
    int i, j, matchLen;

    retStr[0] = '\0';
    if (strsSize > 0) {
        matchLen = strlen(strs[0]);
        for (i = 1; i < strsSize; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < matchLen && strs[0][j] == strs[i][j]; j++)
                continue;
            matchLen = j;
        }
        memcpy(retStr, strs[0], matchLen);
        retStr[matchLen] = '\0';
    }
    return retStr;
}
```